# How to set the time to predict value in evry 120 minute using lstm?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, time, lstm

I have a dataset with three inputs named X1.X2,X3 . So here I tried to predict X1 value in every 120 minutes.

But in my dataset I didn't measure data in every 120 minute. I measured data like after 5 min, or after 10 min, or 30 min soon.

What I want to write is my y value mean prediction value append with every 120 min data from starting time.

I don't know how to write it. Cn anyone help me to solve this problem?

```
X = 1
n_out = 1

x,y=[],[]
start =0

for _ in range(len(data)):
  in_end = start+X
  out_end= in_end + n_out
  if out_end < len(data):
     x_input = data[start:in_end]
    for _ in range(len(x_input)):
        x_input.index = x['time']
        inputs = x_input.resample('5T').apply(lambda x: x[0] if x.count() > 0 else None)
        x.append(inputs) 
    y.append(data[in_end:out_end,1])
    y = y.resample('60min').apply(lambda x: x[0])

start +=1
```

csv file image:

[image]

According to my csv here start time is

> 6:00:00 a.m

sO WHAT I WANT TO SAY after 120 min mean `8:00:00 a.m Y value should be predicted , after that 10:00:00 a.m predict next y value, 12:00:00 p.m next y value predict` like that it should be proceed.

My csv file:

[My csv file](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WWq1qhqi4bGzNir_svQV7VstBkGbocToipPCY83Cclc/edit#gid=1512153575)

Comment: One solution might be to define a `datetime` column from `date` and `time` column. Then, you can groupby by 120min using [`grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html). Finally, on each group, you can apply an interpolation.

Comment: @AlexandreB. how I can only use it for Y value this grouper. Because here I am creating the value for Y. Can you little bit explain with code , if you are okay with tthat?